# Save parameters on 2 different sites

Tags: php, cookies

I have 2 sites, on **each** I have a pop up that appears the first time you visit the site. On this pop up you have a message that let you have 2 choices : stay on the site or visit the other one. You have the option to hide the pop up on your next visit on both (cookie).

**Current scenario :**

I go on site 1, the pop up appears, I choose to go on site 2 and the pop up also appears.

**Desired scenario :**

I go on site 1, the pop up appears, I choose to go on site 2 and the pop up doesn't appears because I come from site 1

Is this possible?

Thank you :)

Comment: How is this related to MySql?

Comment: I thought maybe one possible solution was that you could store a variable on the database and send this variable on the other site database to hide the pop up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be the most easiest to:

I'm on `site1`, get the popup, click on go to `site2` and switch to an url like `site2.com/?popup=no`. `site1` sees the GET argument and does not show a popup, instead places a cookie to hide the popup next time the user visits.

Alternatively, if both sites do have access to the same database, you could save the session ID and the option the user choosed on one site.

Comment: I used your advice and it's working, I came up with this :  

    var url = location.href;
    if (url.indexOf('?popup=no') === -1) {
        console.log("popup yes");
    }
    else{
        e("#popup").css("display", "none")
    }

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. The PHP server variable holds a referrer ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']). If you check that referrer against one of those two sites and show the popup when the referrer is site1 (or two).

Beware though, some user agents do not have support (or hide) the referrer, so it might not be the optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why not trying create cookie from site1 juste before redirecting to site2, if they are on the same domain...

Else, you can add a parameter in the url querystring, or transmit a POST hidden variable, in order to catch this parameter in the site2 and don't pop the popup

Answer (score 0):

Either you store the users choice in some database table (but that would require the user to be logged in before he makes the choice) or you check where the user is coming from on the second site and show the popup conditionally. Google for

```
document.referrer
```

or

```
url parameters javascript
```

Any further help will require effort and code from your side.